# Simple states in rails - state_machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine, states

I'm looking for a recommendation for a simple way the change states of a model in rails. For example, I'd like the user to be able to change their jobs with a dropdown or ratio button to one of the following:

Job States

1. Bids (initial state)
2. In Progress
3. Complete

Is there a simple way to write this in rails or is there a recommended gem? There are no transitions and the user should be able to change from one state to any of the other two in no particular order.

I looked into state_machine which seems a bit hefty for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll cost you $9, but Ryan Bates did a screencast about this very topic not too long ago: http://railscasts.com/episodes/392-a-tour-of-state-machines.

Well worth watching.

Comment: Thanks. Just watched it (I'm a pro member). I might give the last part a try. Still pretty confused on how to trigger the even change with a dropdown or similar.

Comment: I usually use the gem simple_form for that, but that has nothing to do with state machines. Dropdown looks something like: `<%= f.input :state, :collection => %w(bids in_progress complete) %>`

Comment: Also - if want to loop through states (I'm creating an index with a tab for each state), how would I call a particular state? Do I need to create special scopes for this?

Comment: I haven't really looked into it, but I just define a constant in the model. You can use a bit of meta programming to create scopes for every state too.

Comment: Follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885750/loop-through-states-scope-ruby-rails